# Finding a substring while allowing for mismatches with Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, suffix-array

I was reading about a suffix array approach to look for substrings within strings see (http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2007/12/24/The-Suffix-Array/1845)
e.g.

```
sa = SuffixArray.new("abracadabra")
puts sa.find_substring("aca")
```

where SuffixArray is an implementation of a suffix array and find_substring is a method for searching for the position where the substring starts.

My question is how can you implement this search while allowing for a given number of mismatches within the substring? for example,

```
max_mismatches = 2
search_string ="abrazadabra"
substring ="aca"

sa = SuffixArray.new("search_string")
puts sa.find_substring("substring",max_mismatches)
```

Where mismatches may be regarded as an error threshold. in this case it should be able to match "aza" and return the start position of the "aza" substring. Also note that "abr" has 2 mismatches! So it should be returned first. Ideally the approach should return all possible occurences.

Any ideas? or other approaches for solving such a problem?
Thank you

Comment: What you mean by mismatch is not stated clearly. In the example, is it supposed to return 0 since "abr" of the search_string differs from "aca" within 2 mismatches of characters?

Comment: Yes.I agree. Ideally it should return all possible mismatches. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Still is not clear what do you consider a similar string.

Comment: similarity is not very clear or a coherent word to use. but i think you understand what i mean an i have learned of the correct term. hamming distance. Am very greatful for the forum and your comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
# checks whether two strings are similar,
# allowing given number of characters of difference
def similar? a, b, mismatches = 1
  a.chars.zip(b.chars).count{|ca, cb| ca != cb} <= mismatches
end

# in haystack, find similar strings to needle
def find_similar haystack, needle, mismatches = 1
  haystack.chars.each_cons(needle.length).map(&:join).select{|s|
    similar?(s, needle, mismatches)
  }
end

find_similar 'abracadabra', 'aca'
# => ["aca", "ada"] 
find_similar 'abracadabra', 'aca', 2
# => ["abr", "bra", "aca", "ada", "abr", "bra"]
```

Feel free to change `similar?` method to match your definition of similar.

Answer (score 1):

What we're calling mismatches is otherwise known as [Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) which is just a count of how many characters do not match between the strings (allowing only for substitution - not insertion or deletion).

Therefore, Mladen's code to count that can be used in the find_substring function to determine if the string is within the number of allowed mismatches.

Then, if it is, you can return it (or add it to a list of matches if you want to track them all). After that check, you do the test to set high or low depending on if it is greater than or less than the comparison.

Here is how I changed the code:

```
def find_substring(the_substring, n_mismatches)
#uses typical binary search
high = @suffix_array.length - 1
low = 0
while(low <= high)
  mid = (high + low) / 2
  this_suffix = @suffix_array[mid][:suffix]
  compare_len = the_substring.length-1
  comparison = this_suffix[0..compare_len]

  if n_mismatches == 0
    within_n_mismatches = comparison == the_substring
  else
    within_n_mismatches = hamming_distance(the_substring, comparison) <= n_mismatches
  end

  return @suffix_array[mid][:position] if within_n_mismatches

  if comparison > the_substring
    high = mid - 1
  else
    low = mid + 1
  end
end
return nil
end

def hamming_distance(a, b)
# from Mladen Jablanović's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322428/finding-a-substring-while-allowing-for-mismatches-with-ruby 
a.chars.zip(b.chars).count{|ca, cb| ca != cb}
end
```

It will add some processing time - linear with respect to the size of the substring, but I think that may come out as not that much given the size of the rest of the data. I haven't really thought through that part as much as I might, but maybe you want to test it versus another approach: making the changes to your input string and searching it multiple times.

For instance, if you are working with DNA if your substring was "GAC" you would search for that, plus "AAC" and "CAC" and "TAC" (and then the combinations for the nucleotides in the 2nd and 3rd positions. The number of possibilities should keep it small enough to fit in memory.

The opposite - storing all the mismatch possibilities in the suffix array - would not be true. Since it's probably already large, multiplying it by itself a few times is going to make it too large to fit in memory pretty quickly.

I've used that approach before - not quite with a suffix array, but just storing the mismatches in general.

In addition to the code above, I also modified it a bit to add a function for getting all matches. I posted that to [one of my repositories at github](https://github.com/codeodor/miscellany/blob/master/ruby_suffix_array/suffix_array.rb).

Comment: There is a problem with using Hamming Distance so naively as I did here, since we have ordered the suffix array lexicographically and perform binary search, we may never encounter the suffix that is n_mismatches away. See http://www.dcs.kcl.ac.uk/staff/mac/DOC/gsuf-short.pdf for some info (I think) on how to correct this.